# Panel inside a Panel

Tags: css, overriding, sapui5

what i'm trying to do is a panel inside a panel without padding.

[image]

when i write in the developer-mode

```
  .sapUiPanelCont
  {
  padding. 0px !important;
  }
```

my panel has no padding anymore. that's exactly what i need. 
how to override this class with an own name? so others panel got the normal sapUiPanelCont and when i add this class to my control, everything is working like charms.

i've added my styleClass like shown below:

```
 control.addStyleClass("exampleClass");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS selector has to be more specific than the default .sapUiPanelCont one.
[The most specific selector 'wins'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

So you could try to use the selector `.sapUiPanelCont.exampleClass` and omit the !important flag:

```
.sapUiPanelCont.exampleClass
{
  padding: 0px;
}
```

---

You can add the style to a new .css file and reference it in your component metadata/descriptor. See [Table 4 of documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html).

```json
...
"sap.ui5": { 
    "resources":{ //relative urls inside component
        "css": [{
            "uri": "myStyles.css"
        }]
    },
 ...
```

With that the myStyles.css will be added to the html document once as soon as your component is loaded.

Alternatively, if you are using XMLViews, you can [inline the styles into the view](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/b564935324f449209354c7e2f9903f22.html):

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="whatever" xmlns="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
           xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <html:style>
     .sapUiPanelCont.exampleClass
     {
       padding: 0px;
     }
   </html:style>
   <Panel class="exampleClass" text="Outer Panel">
      <Panel text="Inner Panel">
      </Panel>
   </Panel>
</mvc:View>
```